# Apps script get current cell value before it's submitted

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, range

I'm having what appears to be a simple problem, but I don't know if it has a solution or workaround. I'm basically creating a search field for users to query an external database in google sheets, with a search icon (drawing) to execute the script, as below:

[image]

When the user writes the value, hit enter and then click the icon, I get the correct value. But if the user is editing and just clicks the icon, the cell edition is not submitted and the value I get in Range.getValue() is the prior cell value. It's a bit annoying for the user. Is there a workaround to get the value being edited or force the submission of the current value before getting it in apps script? Thanks

Comment: Create a html ui in sidebar or dialog

Comment: It's not possible without some work around. You could always use an onEdit trigger and add some logic so the trigger only runs when B2 is the edited range

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you can do it with a sidebar:

Both functions are in Code.gs:

```
function quizar() {
  var html='Quizar:<br /><form><input type="text" name="text1"/><br /><input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="google.script.run.submit(this.parentNode);" /></form>';
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html));
}

function submit(obj) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet10');
  var rg=sh.getRange(2,2).setValue(obj.text1);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
```

Just run quizar().